# Performing Calculations

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is this the best way to perform calculations on a `webform`? It works, but it seems pretty robust syntax and top heavy if additional `dropdownlists` were going to be added to the `webform`.  Essentially what I need is a way to calculate the item total for each `dropdownlist` which would be ItemPrice * Quantity then add in tax for each item.  Just for further explanation:

> Item1 = $10.00
>   Item1 Quantity = 4
>   Item1Tax = $2.80
>   Item1total= $42.80

```
private double item1price;
private double item1total;
private double item1tax;
private double item2price;
private double item2total;
private double item2tax;
private double item3price;
private double item3total;
private double item3tax;
private double totalprice;
private double totaltax;
private double taxableamt = 0.07;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dropdownforitem1.Text)) 
{ 
    item1total = Convert.ToDouble(item1price)*Convert.ToDouble(quantityfor1.SelectedItem.Text);     
    item1tax = item1total*taxableamt;
    item1total = item1tax+item1total;
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dropdownforitem2.Text)) 
{ 
    item2total = Convert.ToDouble(item2price)*Convert.ToDouble(quantityfor2.SelectedItem.Text);
    item2tax = item2total*taxableamt;
    item2total = item2tax+item2total;       
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dropdownforitem3.Text)) 
{ 
    item3total = Convert.ToDouble(item3price)*Convert.ToDouble(quantityfor3.SelectedItem.Text);     
    item3tax = item3total*taxableamt;
    item3total = item3tax+item3total;
}
totalprice = item1total+item2total+item3total;
totaltax = item1tax+item2tax+item3tax;
```

Comment: You should create a method which does the calculations.

Comment: `itemXprice` is already a double, why are you `Convert.ToDouble` a double? You also have a lot of code duplication that I would try to avoid. Last, when working with money, use the `decimal` data type, not `double`.

Comment: @Sybren - how would I use a method to perform calculations?  Maybe out parameters to pass back the values?

Comment: What values do you need to retain?

Comment: Looks like itemXtotal and itemXtax for each item is what he wants.

Comment: @RamaladFranklin just pass the parameters you need for the calculation to the method and do the calculation in the method. After calculation you can return your result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about creating a method like this?

```
private void CalculateTotals(double unitPrice, string quantity)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Quantity is not valid");
    }

    double itemQuantity = Convert.ToDouble(quantity);
    double subtotal = unitPrice * itemQuantity;
    double itemTax = taxableamt * subtotal;
    double price = subtotal + itemTax;
    totalprice += price;
    totaltax += itemtax;
}
```

Then just have each dropdown call this method like this:

```
CalculateTotals(item1price, quantityfor1.SelectedItem.Text);
```

Comment: after a few minor tweaks this seems to be functioning as requested.  For example the CalculateTotal = (double itemPrice, string quantity) threw multiple compile errorsl

Comment: Sorry I had a couple typos, check the updated version :) Also, since you're new to SO, don't forget to select a correct answer after you're satisfied with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Dictionary of drop downs and process them in a loop, summing the total price and total tax as you go.

Example:

```
var taxableamt = 0.07m;
var dropDowns = new Dictionary<Control,DropDownList>();
dropDowns.Add(dropdownforitem1,quantityfor1);
dropDowns.Add(dropdownforitem2,quantityfor2);
dropDowns.Add(dropdownforitem3,quantityfor3);
// keep going for all drop downs.
var subtotal = 0.0M, tax = 0.0M;
foreach(var item in dropDowns.Keys)
{
    var value = Convert.ToDecimal(item.Text);
    var qty = Convert.ToDecimal(dropDowns[item].SelectedItem.Text);
    var itemsubtotal = value * qty;
    var itemtax = itemsubtotal * taxableamt;
    subtotal+=itemsubtotal;
    tax+=itemtax;
}
var totalprice = subtotal + tax;
```

Comment: Don't see the need for the dictionary. You can just store the drop downs in a list and then access the quantityforX by accessing the selecteditem.text attribute.

Comment: The dictionary matches the item to a quantity drop down and ensures the code never has to figure out which belongs to which.  Without a dictionary you would need two lists indexed the same and loop through them with an integer indexer.  The dictionary allows easy use of foreach on the items to work.

Comment: Or just do List<Tuple<Control, DropDownList>>. I'm not saying that the dictionary is wrong I'm just not use to seeing Dictionaries being iterated. Usually dictionaries are used for look ups only and Lists are used for iterations.

Comment: Dictionaries are great at being enumerated, and the advantage is that you can enumerate from either side, perform all kinds of LINQ on either side, etc.  In the case of this application, if the user adds more items or removes items you don't have to reindex a List or deal with messy Tuples.

Comment: Lists are slightly faster to enumerate though although the performance gain in this scenario would be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to implement is a Shopping cart style of form. If your using ASP.NET webforms, you should have to use Repeater control or GridView control, with each item in the repeater being the Dropdown (Available commodities bound.), a textbox for the quantity and Delete button. Provide an add button to add new rows to the grid.

On clicking Add new button, you need to dynamically add the rows to the grid.  Will have to use ViewState or hidden fields to keep track of the rows being added.

And on the final Calculate button click, need to loop through the repeater items and perform the mentioned calculation on the values obtained from each item.

Hard coding the number of dropdowns is not at all a good practice.

Comment: Yes, trying to calculate prices w/o actually implementing a shopping cart.  Thank you for deciphering what I was after!

Comment: Implementing a dynamic grid using asp.net webforms is little bit tedious. You can try and start using client side frameworks like Angular, Backbone or Ember to make things much easier than maintaining the dynamically added values across postbacks using ViewStates and HiddenFields.